# Angular2 cli error cannot resolve @angular animations from primeng2 components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two modules

App module and gatepassModule

In the appModule

```
  imports: [
   .....other imports
   GatepassModule  //i have imported gatepass module

    ],
   exports: [BrowserModule],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

In the gatepass Module i have

```
import {PanelModule} from "primeng/components/panel/panel";

   @NgModule({
   imports: [SharedModule,
     CommonModule,
     PanelModule, 

   ],
 declarations: [GatepassComponent]

  })
 export class GatepassModule { }
```

The paneModule is a primeng2 module which i have used in the gatepass component as

```
 <p-panel header="Title">
  Content
 </p-panel>
```

Now am getting an error

```
Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in 
 'E:\angular2\gatepass\node_modules
 \primeng\components\panel'
```

[image]

What could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm install @angular/animations --save